# Spring boot - multi module project multiple application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a multi module `spring-boot` maven project. The `parent-project` do not have any code or property file, but has spring-boot, test & basic library dependencies configured.

The `entity-project` inside this that has entities, database configurations & flyway migrations - all configured in its own `entity.yml` file.

Another sibling `rest-project` inside this has REST api codes & its own property file `rest.yml`. This project is dependent on the `entity-project`. As there can only be one application.yml, I renamed each differently to avoid conflict.

However, `rest-project` doesn't load the database configurations without explicitly including the `entity-project` property file, like below

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:entity.yml" }) })
public class CommandServiceApplication { ... }
```

Is this is only way to configure, or am I misconfiguring it?

Comment: One out of the box way would be to rename `entity.yml` to `application-entity.yml`, and add `entity` as an active profile.. :)